# Frontaccounting: onchange not working in selectbox fetched using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, dom-events

```
var replinks = {'a.repopts_link':   function(e) {
    e.onclick = function() {
        save_focus(this);
        set_options(this);
        JsHttpRequest.request(this, null);
        performCustomization();
        return false;
    }
},}

Behaviour.register(replinks);

function performCustomization(){
  selectbox_selector.onchange = function(){
    alert(this.value);
  }
}
```

I am using frontaccounting PHP based application. And I want to perform some task `onchange` value of select box. But form is being loaded by ajax.
I have tried above code but code in `onchange` section not working. If I put alert above `onchange` section so it is working. And I am getting the `selectbox` selector.

Small help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Here are some useful urls
http://frontaccounting.com/
https://sourceforge.net/projects/frontaccounting/